# Developing an initial model with little data

Tags: bayesian, dataset, model

I had a question about working with models when there is little historic data.

For example, if a high school school in its first year of existence wanted to predict how many students would transfer, what could it do? The school doesn't have any historic transfer data to build off of.

Would it make sense to use a bayesian approach using the transfer numbers of other schools in the district as a prior? Or would another approach make sense.

Comment: This question is pretty vague. There are lots of things that could be done. One is to just guess. Another is to build a hierarchical model (it doesn't necessarily need to be Bayesian) to learn about transfer rates of students in similar schools, e.g. high schools in the area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a Bayesian approach where you take other schools of the district as an example, could make sense. But the new school is different from the schools that are already there, and maybe it is better to look at new schools in other districts as a comparison.

It depends on what kind of information you think is important to incorporate, how much time you have for a detailed analysis, and what kind of data you can get your hands on. For example, you may want to use the number of kids in the neighborhood in a model as well, that could be a very important one. Or from a different angle, you may start with a questionnaire on schools in the region that ask them about transferring, and use that data.